# Edição de telas capturadas para confecção de manuais

Tags: documentação

[Obs.: meta: sei que não é sobre programação, mas não tenho certeza dos limites do Stack Overflow PT ainda, então é também um teste para nosso site.]

Ao final do desenvolvimento de um software, chegou o momento de elaborar um manual para o usuário. Para isto, preciso capturar algumas telas e fazer algumas edições:

- aplicar um blur / desfoque em alguma parte da tela;
- aplicar uma máscara que deixe uma parte da tela esmaecida e uma região mais destacada, como se tivesse iluminada;
- desenhar retêngulos ao redor de partes da tela para destacar alguma função;
- acrescentar setas para indicar partes da tela;
- acrescentar textos para explicar partes da tela.

Há algum software para fazer isto? A princípio qualquer programa de edição de imagens serviria, mas sempre falta alguma coisa nos programas que eu utilizo. Por ex., no Gimp não é fácil acrescentar retângulos e setas.

[meta: outro ponto, sobre respostas: talvez fosse o caso de cada resposta indicar apenas um programa, para que os programas mais úteis pudessem ser mais votados]

Comment: A pergunta trata um problema interessante, mas na sua forma actual vão existir muitas respostas todas elas baseadas numa opinião pessoal. Vamos esperar para ver o que a comunidade acha mas eu estou a "segurar" o voto para fechar como "principalmente baseadas em opiniões".

Comment: @Zuul talvez não, pois é possível haver uma resposta de "existe o software XYZ que permite filtros de blur, desenhos geométricos, setas que podem ser posicionadas em qquer direção e escrever texto com várias cores/fontes".

Comment: O Illustrator faz tudo isso. Provavelmente outras ferramentas de edição vetorial também.

Comment: @woliveirajr Eu não estou contra ti, longe disso, mas sou Designer à +/- 18 anos e digo-te, existe um leque enorme de aplicações para esse fim. Por outro lado não nos podemos esquecer que o teu problema está na "zona cinzenta" de relacionados com programação, mas não é claramente um problema de programação e seus derivados :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez [essa resposta no Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/532/947) seja útil pra você.

Usando o [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org) você pode capturar as imagens e já trabalhar com elas na forma de "quadro branco", podendo fazer indicações, anotações e outras coisas.

A ferramenta disponibiliza diversos recursos para trabalhar com a imagem, como sombras, motion blur etc.

Answer (score 2):

Não existe uma ferramenta ideal para esta confecção, mas um conjunto de ferramentas.

O *Microsoft Word* tem os seguintes recursos:

- Desenhar retângulos ao redor de partes da tela para destacar alguma função;
- Acrescentar setas para indicar partes da tela;
- Acrescentar textos para explicar partes da tela.

Possui também vários tipos de índices (analítico, remissivo) e vários recursos de formatação de textos.

Para edição de imagens, há o *Adobe Photoshop*. Ele possui os seguintes recursos:

- Aplicar um blur / desfoque em alguma parte da tela;
- Aplicar uma máscara que deixe uma parte da tela esmaecida e uma região mais destacada, como se tivesse iluminada;

Alternativamente, há soluções livres para este tipo de edição:

**Processadores de Texto**

- Apache OpenOffice: http://www.openoffice.org/pt-br/
- LibreOffice: http://pt-br.libreoffice.org/
- AbiWord: http://abisource.com/
- KWord (integrante do KOffice, apenas Linux): http://www.koffice.org/kword/

**Editores de Imagem**

- Paint.NET: http://www.getpaint.net/
- GIMP: http://www.gimp.org.